# Highlight/Format textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, diff, tinymce

I'm looking to implement a live diff inside a webpage that preserves whitespace.

I've done something similar in the past using a combination of TinyMCE and JQuery in IE6 (required for that project) but it didn't preserve whitespace.  (It wasn't supposed to, but I didn't add anything to make it do that, it just did).  TinyMCE wasn't ideal as I was dealing with plain text, and TinyMCE is a WYSIWYG style editor supporting rich text.  Most of it's functionality wasn't being used and is/was hard to disable.

I've looked through most of the projects listed at  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors.  EditArea seemed promising, but I cannot seem to determine which elements are actually being used to display the text.

> $('#frame_modified').contents().find('#editor').text()

displays a lot of the line information (123456789101112 and so on) along with the line the cursor is under, but not the rest.  I haven't figured out how to apply/modify the styles associated with that.

Lets say the user types foo, I'd like to wrap it so it displays as <span class="bar">foo</span> on the fly.  What's the simplest solution to go about getting this sort of functionality?

IE8 is the target browser for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some action on the onKeyDown event (in one of your own plugins). If your cursor is already in a new span add the character just typed in else create a new span with the character entered. Something like this:

```
ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed,evt){
  char = getChar(evt.keyCode); // your function to get the character to be inserted depending on evt.keyCode

  // if span already exists
  node = ed.selection.getNode();
  if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'span' && node.className == 'myclass'){
     node.innerHTML += char;
  }
  // new span
  else {
    doc = ed.getDoc();
    new_element = doc.createElement('span');
    new_element.className = "myclass";
    new_element.innerHTML = char;
    tinymce.activeEditor.mceInsertContent(new_element);
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out and see how it goes.  It maybe some time however as I'm on vacation until Monday starting in a few hours. -- If I can get this to work for me with whitespace and all, before I can accept this as an answer, I'd like a few edits to the code. var declarations to char/node/doc/new_element, === instead of == for the string compares, and a semicolon at the end is all I'm seeing at the moment.